# Popover keeps presenting modally

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I'm trying to add a popover when an image is tapped but it keeps being presented modally. Every answer to this question/ topic suggest to add *adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController* but it won't work for me. I'm trying to do this on an iPhone. Here's my code:

```
class ParkingInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    ...
    func presentPopover(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
    let infoViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ImagesInfoPopupViewController")
    infoViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    infoViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 75)

    let popoverPresentationViewController = infoViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = sender.view
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: sender.locationInView(sender.view).x,
        y: sender.locationInView(sender.view).y,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)

    self.presentViewController(infoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

The cell with the image is:

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AppConstants.moreInfoCellReusableIdentifier) as! MoreInfoTableViewCell

        let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(presentPopover))
        tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.securityImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
        cell.securityImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

        return cell
```

Answer (score 4):

## The following is for a Swift 3 (Xcode 8) solution

I faced this problem when migrating from Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7) to Swift 3 (Xcode 8).

For the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` I implemented both below:

```
public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

While preparing for the segue I did the following in `prepare(for segue...)`:

```
let popover = segue.destination
popover.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
popover.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

Assuming that you have a class for your popover controller, in `viewDidLoad()` you can replicate the following:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
...
self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 123, height: 456)
```

And finally, my segue that is defined in the storyboard is configured as the following:

- Kind: Present As Popover
- Anchor: A Button Bar Item (will vary for your implementation)
- Directions: All checked by default

Answer (score 0):

Also add:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
    return .None
}
```